# What can I do with all this Ebonstone?

Tags: terraria

I've been making an underground road across my map from the spawn point to the dungeon, but I've been wondering what I should do with the stacks Ebonstone I picked up on my way through the corruption. Anything I've read has indicated the using it as a building material might not be a good idea.
so, should I just purify it all? Or is there something else I can do/make with it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You shouldn't use it as a building material because the presence of a lot of Ebonstone causes the sky and music transition seen in the Corruption, and allows Corrupted enemies to spawn.

What you *could* do with it:

- Place it in your inventory's trash slot to get rid of it; use [<kbd>Shift</kbd>-Click](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/what-keyboard-shortcuts-are-in-terraria/28353#28353) for maximum efficiency.
- Place it, then purify it to get more Stone, if you happen to be short on that (which will never happen because half the map is Stone).
- Store it on the assumption that it does something useful at some point in the future.
- Use it to lock a passage to players who don't have a Nightmare Pickaxe or higher yet. Then again, other materials, such as Obsidian or Hellstone, would be better suited for such purposes.
- Use it to build a Corrupted enemy grinder for infinite Rotten Chunks.

As of patch 1.1, there are also a few more "real" uses:

- You can combine it with Demonite Ore to make [Demonite Bricks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demonite_Brick), which *are* a feasible building material.
- After unlocking hardmode, the Corruption can spread via Stone Blocks as well, so you can get an Underground Corruption going by planting a few Ebonstone Blocks, then waiting for them to spread.

Comment: Only thing I can add is to help farm [Vile Mushroom](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Vile_Mushroom).

Comment: @TomWijsman That doesn't grow on Ebonstone, though.

Comment: @lunboks: But Ebonstone spreads corruption, or is there an alternative way?

Comment: @TomWijsman - I already have a Vile Mushroom farm. All I needed was dirt and corruption seeds.

Comment: I wouldn't dump it yet, at least stuff it in a chest or something.  You never know what the creators of the game will add.  Not that Ebonstone is difficult to acquire, however.

Comment: If you're playing multiplayer, replace someone's stone home with ebonstone and see how long it takes them to notice.

Comment: We usually write childish messages about other players' mothers in ebonstone, then frame it in lava and obsidian and/or hellstone. Perhaps our players have different objectives, though.